# How to access global SASS mixin function in angular2 individual component?

Tags: css, angular, sass, scss-lint

i have a common SCSS mixin function in global SCSS file. but i could not able to access that mixin function inside the angular2 components.

i have global style.scss which have following mixin function

```css
@mixin respond-to($breakpoint) {
  @if $breakpoint == "small" {
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else if $breakpoint == "medium" {
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else if $breakpoint == "large" {
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

i am trying to access this mixin function in component.scss like

```css
.procard{
width:50%;
 @include respond-to(small){ 
  .pro-card{
    width: 100%;
    .pro-box{
      max-width: 320px;
      margin:0 auto;
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

While running this it show error

[image]

Comment: did you got my question?

Comment: `@import` `component.scss` in `style.scss` after `respond-to` definition.

Comment: @MaheswaranS. Did you found a answer to this question. Have the same requirement!!

Comment: @bhavya_w. Not yet found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Import the `Mixin lib` into all your component `.scss` files, where you want to use them. `phpStorm` will still say, that he cant find this `mixin`, but compiler will find it.

Answer (score 0):

you can explicitly import the global scss. **OR** a better way is to
use the `sass-resources-loader` which helps you using shared scss among components without having to explicit importing them. Something like:

`{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loader: ["raw-loader", "sass-loader",
     {
       loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
       options: {
       resources: ['./styles/global/_vars.scss', './styles/global/_mixins.scss']
       },
      }
     ]
  }`